# Data binding: Not call onClick method

Tags: android-databinding

Android 4.3+

I trt to use data binding. I use official documentation from here [Data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)

So in **app/build.gradle**:

```
dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```

In my xml layout file:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>    
        <variable
            name="handler"
            type="com.myproject.SettingsFragment" />    
    </data>    
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">    
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"                >

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/contentContainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                        android:id="@+id/contactUsContainer"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:onClick="@{handler::onClickContactUs}">    

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/contactUsTextView"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>    

                    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>        
                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>    
</layout>
```

And here my fragment **SettingsFragment.java**:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void onClickContactUs(View view) {     
    }
}
```

But when I click on container **contactUsContainer** the method `onClickContactUs()` is NOT call.
Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're experiencing a common problem. First, you must inflate the binding using the binding inflate() call. Second, you must set the binding variables:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     MyLayoutBinding binding = MyLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
     binding.setHandler(this);
     return binding.getRoot();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

userDetailViewBinding=DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_user_detail_view, container, false);
        ProfileViewModel.Factory factory = new ProfileViewModel.Factory(getActivity().getApplication());

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory)
                .get(ProfileViewModel.class);
        observeViewModel(viewModel);
        userDetailViewBinding.setProfileViewModel(viewModel);
        userDetailViewBinding.setUserDetailViewFrag(this);
        return userDetailViewBinding.getRoot();
    }
```

Comment: my project i convert mvp to mvvm.i see that issue. so i add this line the issue is resolved  (    userDetailViewBinding.setUserDetailViewFrag(this); )

Comment: please add description to your answer how it solved problem and what it does exactly?